# AnnotationTransactionAspect is not recreated for @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

Since I migrated from Spring 3.2.6 to Spring 4.1.2 my tests are not working.
I found out that `AnnotationTransactionAspect` (`TransactionAspectSupport`) now caches the `PlatformTransactionManager` in `transactionManagerCache` field.

I use `MockHttpServletRequest` to emulate end-to-end tests.
My tests are not transactional and they don't rollback.

My tests use `@DirtiesContext`. After Spring closes the old context and creates a new one all beans are recreated except `AnnotationTransactionAspect`. `AnnotationTransactionAspect` is not recreated and contains cache from the previous test. That means that it contains cached `PlatformTransactionManager`. So when `@Transactional` method is called inside a service layer it tries to get a Database Connection from cached Transaction Manager, but cached Transaction Manager has a datasource that was already closed. It was closed when Spring was shutting down Application context after the first test.

So my question is why `AnnotationTransactionAspect` is not recreated?

**UPDATED** add exception

```
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:439) ~[spring-tx-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:64) ~[spring-aspects-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.core.service.user.UserProvider.resetPassword(UserProvider.java:98) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xxx.core.api.rest.UserController.resetPassword(UserController.java:117) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:145) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.core.service.ControllerHelper.method(ControllerHelper.java:65) [test-classes/:na]
    at com.xxx.core.integration.controller.UserControllerTest.method(UserControllerTest.java:110) [test-classes/:na]
    at com.xxx.core.integration.controller.UserControllerTest.resetPasswordSuccessXXX(UserControllerTest.java:132) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162) [spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:159) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser] ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.assertCpds(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:447) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:459) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you enable spring debug level logs and see whats happening behind the scenes?

Comment: I already did that. I created two tests that are the same. They run one after another. The first works fine and the second crashes with the exception. I compared two logs with winMerge. They are really the same. The only difference is that first log has some Hibernate static initialization (just properties, nothing interesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in Spring. 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12518
It was fixed in 4.1.4

Comment: In my case I had another issue with DirtiesContext: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8849 Briefly: I had tests with different profiles activated and instead of creating two in-memory databases it shared the same database between different contexts. DirtiesContext closed the first context and dropped the database, the second test failed because hibernate sequence wasn't found.